# No Build Process Templates available in TFS 2015

Tags: tfs, build, tfs-2015

I'm trying to create a new Build Definition in TFS 2015 but when I get to the Process section there are no templates available for me to select. This server was upgraded from 2013 to 2015. I don't know if the templates existed in 2013. How do I get the default templates?

[image]

**Update**
Found TfvcTemplate.12.xaml [here](http://blogs.objectsharp.com/post/2014/02/27/Release-Management-Build-Template.aspx), added it to source control, clicked new browsed to it and still nothing.

Comment: Have you configured XAML build service? Are you able to select build controller in "Build Default" tab?

Comment: Yes I can select a build controller in the Build Default tab, XAML Build Service is configured

Comment: You should consider using the new build system and not the Legacy Xaml Build system. I don't expect it to ship in the next version of TFS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask the admin to check your account's permission in the **Security** of XAML Build Definition, it seems you don't have **View build definition** permission:

[image]

Comment: Yea turns out one of the groups I was in was denying me permission